# Duplicate Cron Jobs Using wp_next_scheduled / wp_schedule_event

Tags: hooks, wp-cron, duplicates

I'm working on a plugin to register and schedule various cron jobs. I am:

- using [WP Crontrol](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-crontrol/) (just to see all of my cron jobs and override them if need be)
- have a server cron job set up and have `define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);` in place

When I went into 'Cron Events' within Crontrol I saw that some functions were added literally hundreds of times. Specifically, in 'Cron Events' the function is what's getting registered/listed, not the hook. A simplified version of my code:

```
class My_Cron_Manager {

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct() {

        add_filter( 'wp', array( $this, 'my_schedule_cron_jobs' ) );
        add_action( 'my_cron_event_func', array( $this, 'my_cron_job_func' ));

    }

    /**
     * Schedule cron Jobs
     */
    public static function my_schedule_cron_jobs() {

        if (! wp_next_scheduled ( 'my_cron_job_func' )) {
            wp_schedule_event(time(), 'twicedaily', 'my_cron_job_func');
        };

    }

    /**
     * My Function
     */
    public static function my_cron_job_func() {

        // Do Stuff

    }

}

new My_Cron_Manager();
```

I have a suspicion that I had an error in my code that was re-registering the function, but I'm not entirely sure. Am I utilizing `wp_next_scheduled` and `wp_schedule_event` correctly?

Can someone please let me know if my above code would be causing duplicated hook/function registration?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I see `new My_Cron_Manager();` at the end of the file, but where and how is this called? Also `wp` is an action hook, I believe, not a filter (semantics, I know). But where is the action hook `my_cron_event_func` and how is that called?

Comment: Thanks @hwl  I'm not entirely sure how I was calling it, but just updated this thread via an answer with updated code that appears to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well I believe that I have things working correctly. I'd be curious if anyone has any more insights, but I believe what was happening:

- I was calling my class incorrectly
- I was referencing a class function in `wp_next_scheduled` and  `wp_schedule_event` when I should have been referencing a callback/hook.

My revised code (which has been tested and I can confirm works).

---

```
define( 'MY_CRON_FILE', __FILE__ );

class MY_Cron_Manager {

    /**
    * Hook in methods.
    */
    public static function init() {

        register_activation_hook( MY_CRON_FILE, array(__CLASS__, 'my_schedule_cron_jobs' ));
        add_action( 'my_cron_job_event_func', array( __CLASS__, 'my_cron_job_func' )); //

    }

    /**
     * Schedule cron Jobs
     */
    public static function my_schedule_cron_jobs() {

        if (! wp_next_scheduled ( 'my_cron_job_event_func' )) {
            wp_schedule_event(time(), 'twicedaily', 'my_cron_job_event_func');
        };

    }

    /**
     * My Function
     */
    public static function my_cron_job_func() {

        // Do Stuff

    }

}

MY_Cron_Manager::init();
```